# Referencing a Theorem in a Paper?

Tags: soft-question, article-writing

I'm making the final edits for a paper and I have a question more about the etiquette. I want to use a theorem from another paper and its obvious I have to cite it, but do I need to prove it too? I previously just used it as a fact and cited it, but it was recommended to make it into a theorem in order to make it easier to reference later.

If I do need to prove it, can I just use the proof from the reference (with citation, of course)?

The paper is on graph theory, specifically exponential domination. Thanks!

Comment: not an expert or anything, but isn't it quite unnecessary if there's already another paper where it's proven?

Comment: You may be suit yourself better ask it in academic stack exchange

Comment: If the proof is long or involved, I would simply state it and refer to the other paper, unless you actually need parts of the proof rather than just the theorem. If the proof is short or has a simple basic idea, I would probably sketch the proof or indicate its main idea, though it would be perfectly acceptable simply to refer the reader to the other paper.

Comment: Perhaps make an exception and give a proof "for the convenience of the reader" If the paper is in some obscure journal or not widely understood language, e.g., in *Matematikai Lapok* which I understand has published some good papers on graph theory.

Answer (score 3):

No you can state and  refer to original paper as reference.